# How to merge two sentences?

Tags: word-choice, word-order

I need your help in merging these two sentences in one and short.

```
  For the evaluation, three statistical criteria were used: correlation coefficient 
  (R), root mean squared difference (RMSD), and bias. Global R, RMSD, and bias maps 
   were averaged taking into account contrasted biomes and vegetation (via the Leaf 
     Area Index; LAI).
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing advice.

Comment: There's no need to merge them. It will just make the passage more difficult to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [semicolon](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/sentences/rules-for-combining-sentences.html) to join the sentences together. A replacement of the full stop (period) with a semicolon should be sufficient. If you wish to edit the sentence down too, I suggest:

> Three statistical criteria were used for the evaluation, the correlation coefficient (R), the root-mean-squared difference (RMSD) and the bias; global maps of these were averaged, taking into account contrasted biomes and vegetation (via the Leaf Area Index; LAI).

Comment: is there a coma after the evaluation

Answer (score 0):

For the evaluation, three statistical criteria were used: correlation coefficient 
  (R), root mean squared difference (RMSD), and bias, with Global R, RMSD, and bias maps 
   being averaged, taking into account contrasted biomes and vegetation (via the Leaf 
     Area Index; LAI).